# Arbitrary power integration problem

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I solve the following problem.Using u substituion.

$$\int\frac{\log_5(x)}{x} \, dx$$

I am know $\log_5(x)$ is the same as $\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(5)}$ But how would I proceed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\int \frac{\log_5{x}}{x}\,dx = \int \frac{\ln x}{x\ln 5}\,dx = \frac{1}{\ln 5} \int  \underbrace{\ln{x}}_{\large u}\cdot \underbrace{\frac 1x\,dx}_{\large \,du} = \frac1{2\ln 5}(\ln{x})^2 + C$$

Comment: I see would it make sense If it written as $\frac{1}{\ln(5)} \frac{ln(x)^2}{2}$

Comment: Indeed it would make sense.

Comment: That makes senses thanks

Comment: You're welcome, @Fernando. Good to see you 'round again! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Nice feedback + 1

Answer (score 2):

$$\int dx \frac{\log{x}}{x} = \int d(\log{x}) \log{x} = \frac12 (\log{x})^2 + C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{As }\log_ab=\frac{\log_cb}{\log_ca}\implies \log_5x=\frac{\ln x}{\log_5e}$$

$$\implies\int \frac{\log_5x}x dx=\frac1{\log_e5}\int\frac{\ln x}xdx$$

---

Again,  $\log_ab\cdot\log_bd=\frac{\log_cb}{\log_ca}\cdot \frac{\log_cd}{\log_cb}=\frac{\log_cd}{\log_ca}=\log_ad$

$\implies \log_5x=\log_ex\cdot\log_5e$

$$\implies \int \frac{\log_5x}x dx=\log_5e\int\frac{\ln x}xdx$$

Now put $\ln x=u$

Comment: No need for integration by parts! $u = \ln x$, $$du = \dfrac 1x \,dx \iff \int u\,du$$

Comment: @amWhy, agreed & rectified

Comment: How were you able to take out the $log_5$ out the integral?

Comment: @FernandoMartinez, as $\int af(x)dx=a\int f(x)dx$ if $a$ is independent of $x$

Comment: Oh I see that seems to make sense.

Comment: Then for my final answer I got $\frac{\ln(x)^2}{2}+c$

Comment: @FernandoMartinez, its $$\log_5e\cdot\frac{(\ln x)^2}2+C,$$ right?

Comment: Will the down-voter please disclose the mistake here that has caused the down-vote?

Comment: @amWhy, isn't $$\log_5e=\frac1{\log_e5}?$$

Comment: @amWhy, I have just shown the possible forms of the constant. Is that the reason for the down-vote?